# NGINX not serving files

Tags: nginx, webserver

So I have some an NGINX configuration that looks like this:

```
limit_req_zone $http_cf_connecting_ip zone=api:10m rate=20r/s;
server {
    server_name smokese.sh;
    server_name www.smokese.sh;
    root /home/SmokeSesh/Smoke/dist;
    try_files $uri @web;
    location /.well-known { try_files $uri =403; }
    location /assets {
      try_files $uri @web;
    }
    location @web { proxy_pass http://localhost:8000; }
    # API
    location /api/ {
      limit_req zone=api burst=20 nodelay;
      limit_req_status 429;
      add_header cache-control "no-store, max-age=0"; # Disable cache on API routes
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    }
}
```

Now my question is, is what could possibly be stopping it from serving files to `/assets`. It always just fall's back, and yes `root` does exist.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with NGINX itself or with my configuration, but help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you remove the `try_files` statement and restart Nginx, the error log should give you the reason for the failures.

Comment: After removing `try_files` and reloading, I get no error message of any kind, it just reloads properly.